# Как заполнить массив элементами с клавиатуры?

Tags: java

---

Дан массив. Определить количество максимальных элементов в массиве

В первой строке задается количество элементов массива (не более 100)

Во второй строке вводятся элементы массива.

---

Я знаю, как найти максимальное значение в массиве со случайными числами, но как запихнуть в массив элементы с клавиатуры (как в задаче), если они написаны в строку через пробел? И как потом работать с ними?

Comment: Задания лучше приводить текстом.

Comment: А что значит "количество максимальных элементов"?

Comment: @LEQADA сколько раз максимальный элемент встречается в массиве

Comment: Прочитайте о `Scanner` в Java. С его помощью будете вводить элементы с клавиатуры.

Comment: @LEQADA как вводить элементы понятно, а как запихнуть их в массив?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Отвечу на вопрос "Как заполнить массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры".
Для этого нам понадобится `Scanner`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Объявляем Scanner
    System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
    int size = input.nextInt(); // Читаем с клавиатуры размер массива и записываем в size
    int array[] = new int[size]; // Создаём массив int размером в size
    System.out.println("Insert array elements:");
    /*Пройдёмся по всему массиву, заполняя его*/
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt(); // Заполняем массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры
    }
    System.out.print ("Inserted array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print (" " + array[i]); // Выводим на экран, полученный массив
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

А дальше работайте с массивом так же, как работали раньше с массивом, заполненным случайными числами.

Answer (score 1):

а вот для `ArrayList`, переработал немного, пробуем добавлять с помощью `NameofList.add(something)`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Объявляем Scanner
        System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
        int size = input.nextInt(); // Читаем с клавиатуры размер массива и записываем в size

        List<Integer> SubArray2 = new ArrayList<>(); // Создаём массив int размером в size

         System.out.println("Insert array elements:");
        /*Пройдёмся по всему массиву, заполняя его*/

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            SubArray2.add(input.nextInt()); // Заполняем массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры
        }

        System.out.print ("Inserted array elements:");
        System.out.println(SubArray2);
        }
```

Comment: Неправда, вы создаете объект класса ArrayList без указания параметров, значит ArrayList будет содержать внутри массив размерностью 10(по дефолту).

Answer (score 0):

Так, вроде, красивше!?

```
public static void main(String[] agrs)
{
    int[] a = new int[7];
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


    for (int element : a)
    {       

        System.out.print("Введите " + (i + 1) + "-й элемент массива: ");
        a[i] = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(a[i] + " - ");

        i++;
    }

    for (int element : a)

        System.out.print(element + " ");


}
```

Или так:

```
public static void main(String[] agrs)
{
    int[] a = new int[7];
    int i = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int element : a)
    {       

        System.out.print("Введите " + (i + 1) + "-й элемент массива: ");
        a[i] = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(a[i] + " - ");

        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Comment: И как ваш код связан с вопросом? У вас просто задание элементов в массив с клавиатуры без последующих действий.

Comment: @Denis а какие там предполагаются последующие действия?

Comment: @Иггр вы объявляете массив `[7]`, а нужен массив длины, задаваемой числом из первой строки.

Comment: @NickVolynkin найти количество максимальных элементов же. А вообще да, я плохо прочитал вопрос, затруднения то заключались в вводе элементов массива с клавиатуры)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PerBor_Mas {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int n = vvod.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[n];
        int k = vvod.nextInt();

        Scanner vvod = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите длину одномерного массива");


        System.out.println("Введите первый элемент массива");

        System.out.println("Водится массив");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(A[i] + k + "\t");
            k++;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Ввод одномерного массива с клавиатуры.

Comment: Пользуйтесь кнопкой  [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/789984/edit) для правки ответа.