# Заполнить двумерный массив вводом с клавиатуры на java

Tags: java

Добрый вечер!

Стоит такая задача:
Создать двумерный массив N на M и заполнить его вводом из клавиатуры.
Первым делом через пробел вводим N и M, а затем в зависимости от его размеров вводим что должно быть в каждой ячейке в таком формате:

```
Input format:
4 6 
010101
111111
101011
101000
```

Получить массив размерами N на M - проблем не составило. Но как заполнить его именно в таком формате, как показан выше? Если я использую 2 цикла for - то у меня считывает только первый символ в каждой строке на каждой итерации цикла.

```
    int N; 
    int M;
    String[][] inputData;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    N = sc.nextInt();
    M = sc.nextInt();
    inputData = new String[N][M];
    for(int i=0; i<inputData.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<inputData[i].length;j++){
            inputData[i][j] = sc.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

---

Похожее решение для простого массива есть тут. Но не смог его применить для двумерного массива.
[Как заполнить массив элементами с клавиатуры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458979/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: UPDATE!!!!  ввод должен быть СТРОК! то что указано 010101 - это для примера. В реальности будет ввод символов # и .

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам осталось распилить полученную строку на символы и записать по ячейкам.

```
for(int i=0; i<inputData.length; i++){
    char[] in = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for(int j=0; j<inputData[i].length;j++){
        inputData[i][j] = in[j];
    }
}
```

Вы уверены что вам нужен String[][] может все таки char[][]?